# Web application cannot establish connection to database

Tags: java, database, eclipse, tomcat, war

My application, when running on Tomcat, is not able to connect to my database when deployed as a .war in the webapps folder, but it can connect when I am running it through Eclipse directly. The code is exactly the same in both cases. In addition, other apps in the webapps folder, which originally could connect to the database, can no longer do so. The jdbc code is correct as I have tested it with offline applications or when running it through eclipse, but  not when I access it on, say, Chrome, using localhost. What has happened to my tomcat server?

Note: the JDBC driver is the MS Access one.

Comment: Please post the relevant code. If you say there is a problem, then clearly something is wrong in the code or the server configuration. We can help you best if you show us the relevant code. Thank you.

Comment: not everybody has seen your previous questions...you need to edit the question with details of the JDBC driver you are using. I'm guessing that it is the JDBC-ODBC to MS Access as this was the subject of your last question.

Comment: I think it's the server configuration. I will post the exact code in an hour or so because the computer containing that code is currently not working.

Answer (score 1):

> The code is exactly the same in both cases.

No it's not; if it were exactly the same you'd be connecting properly.

> but it can connect when I am running it through Eclipse directly

Does this mean that you have a main method that drives the code that connects properly?  The way you do it is usually different from a web app - you know that, right?

If you could post an exception or log message it would help a great deal.

I'm guessing it could be any one of the following; guessing is necessary because you haven't provided enough information for a solid answer:

1. The JDBC driver JAR is not available when you run under one configuration; you'll see a `ClassNotFoundException` in that case.
2. You haven't configured a [JNDI data source](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) properly in Tomcat.
3. You didn't put the JDBC driver JAR in the Tomcat /lib directory.

Could be other possibilities.

UPDATE:

Since you're using Access, and providing no other information, I'm guessing that you're using a relative file path to get to the Access `.mdb` file.  Your command line app that runs successfully in Eclipse works because you give a relative file path that is correct relative to the project root.  When you deploy to Tomcat, that relative path is no longer correct, so your application can't find the database anymore.

Sounds like you aren't printing the stack trace for errors, so you're losing out on information that might help you figure this out.

Microsoft Access is not a multi-user database.  A web based application running on Tomcat is certainly multi-threaded.  You should not be using Access for a web application.  I'd consider switching to another database.

Comment: It is the same, I know this because I have run the application from eclipse, and then immediately afterwards clicked Export as WAR and put this in the tomcat webapps directory, after which I restart the server and access my application.
The exception is a NullPointerException at DatabaseHelper:XXX. XXX is a line that says something like "PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement", and conn is the instance variable of type Connection. Each helper method calls the private method getConnection() before doing anything else, which initializes conn to a connection. I copy pasted the getConnection

Comment: body to an offline application, which successfully opened a connection.

It could be any of your 3 guesses, but I thought that the JDBC Jar was a bootstrap class in rt.jar so it does not need to be explicitly loaded, put in the classpath, or put in /lib.

Comment: Note that the exception doesn't come up immediately, I can still access the homepage and forms but as soon as a form is submitted and the servlet calls one of the helper methods that accesses or updates the database, this NullPointerException occurs.
DatabaseHelper is my helper class containing methods for updating and getting database items, fyi

Comment: You never said anything about MS Access until after I answered.  You're right; you don't put anything in the /lib directory in that case.  Sounds like you aren't making a connection.  I think Access and the JDBC-ODBC driver is a mistake.

Comment: Where do you think the mistake is, though? Like I said it works in an offline app and when running it through Eclipse, and I made sure that the connection establishing code is the exact same.

Comment: Ok, I tried to simplify the problem. I made a simple servlet that gets the first item in a database and prints it, or prints the exception. It wasn't a ClassNotFound exception, but a SQLException. It says, Could not find file '(unknown)'. When I pasted identical code into an offline app (changing the out.println to System.out.println of course) it did fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to verify the path to your database file.  In fact, I believe it has to be an absolute path for tomcat to work correctly.  The simplest thing to do is to put your database file in C:\data or similar and then hard code the path in your code.  Of course, the file will be outside of your war and thus not portable (i.e., deployable to a remote server).

Second, you do need to make sure that the JDBC driver is available.  If you use Class.forName in your code to load the driver, you will only need to make sure that the jar containing the driver is in the tomcat classpath (which would include the lib directory of your webapp).  If you use the -Djdbc.drivers JVM flag approach, you will need to add it to the tomcat startup scripts.

Comment: So to put the entire thing on a different computer, I would need to transfer the .war and .mdb file, and then set up the ODBC connection on that computer, right?

Comment: Correct... and the path will need to be the exact same as well.